# Filter in microsoft Excel to remove rows which have values from another column

Tags: excel

I have the requirement to apply filter on a column using data from another column in Microsoft Excel.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 |  |
| 4 |  |
| 5 | 4 |

Result :

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 |  |
| 5 | 4 |

The outcome should be the rows of column A which are not available in Column B.

Is there any way to do such filtering in Microsoft Excel ?

Answer (score 1):

If your version of Excel doesn't support `FILTER` you can use this formula instead:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$5,SMALL(IF(ISNA(MATCH($A$1:$A$5,$B$1:$B$5,0)),ROW($A$1:$A$5)),ROW(D1:D1))),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel supports `FILTER` you can use `=FILTER(A1:B5,ISNA(MATCH(A1:A5,B1:B5,0)))`

Depending on how the blank cells are defined, you may get 0s instead of blanks in column B.  To get around this I do `=IF(A1:B5="","",A1:B5)` and then use the code above on the result.

[More on FILTER function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759)